# How can I enable Vista/Win 7 theming/style for a ToolTip control?

Tags: user-interface, winapi, windows-7, windows-vista, visual-styles

In Windows Vista and Windows 7, ToolTips have a new visual style or theme, they are shiny grey metallic. How can I enable the new style for a ToolTip control?

Some controls, like ListViews and ToolBars, use the new tooltips automatically, but other tooltips are rendered with the old yellow XP style.

I've tried sending an [TTM_SETWINDOWTHEME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760418.aspx) message but nothing happens and I'm not sure what string I am supposed to use for the visual style name.

[SetWindowTheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759827%28VS.85%29.aspx) doesn't work either, I've used it successfully on ListViews and TreeViews to set the "Explorer" style (see http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/TreeViewVista.aspx), but that doesn't seem to work on ToolTips.

I'm using the plain win32 C API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you specified TTS_USEVISUALSTYLE as the window style on your tooltips?